# EmberJS access Ember.Object in Ember.Controller

Tags: ember.js

My purpose is to separate a lot of boilerplate code in an Object, but I know how to access this Object in my Controller.

The code looks like this.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
"use strict";

var panel = Ember.Object.extend({

});
const Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    init() {
        this.set('shoppingList', ['eggs', 'cheese']);
    }
});


export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    panel: null,
```

Comment: which part do you consider boilerplate code ? side note : Always call this._super(...arguments) in init method.

Comment: It is only an example i want to know how i could create an instance of e.g. Person within the Controller, because at runtime the scope of the init method of the controller doesnt see the person object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create object for Person class and assign it to controller properties.

Arrays and objects defined directly on any `Ember.Object` are shared across all instances of that object. When a new instance is created, its `init()` method is invoked automatically. This is the ideal place to implement setup required on new instances. [reference](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_initializing-instances)

```
const Panel = Ember.Object.extend({

});
const Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.set('shoppingList', ['eggs', 'cheese']); 
    }
});
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    panel: Panel.create(),
    init(){
       this._super(...arguments);
       this.set('person',Person.create());
```

Comment: I suggest doing inside the Controller's `init` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I was unspecific, I meant doing the Person.creates in the init instead of the class declaration!